# testing devise login with cucumber

Tags: authentication, devise, cucumber

I know the ideal thing to do would be to fill the login form and follow that flow. The thing is that I am not using devise for login in. I do login in my application the user after authenticating with Facebook and fb_graph gem.

So the devise sign_in view only has the link "connect with Facebook", but I am able to see that route, and I assume that will try to sign_in a user if a post is made to that url.

I tried doing a post to the sign_in (which view is empty) directly with cucumber, and even though the response is ok, the user is not logged in.

```
Given /^I am a logged in user$/ do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  res = post("/users/sign_in", :email => @user.email, :password => "password")
  p res
end
```

How can I test this?

Thanks,

UPDATE:

The scenario looks like this:

```
Scenario: Going to the index page
  Given I am a logged in user
  And there is a subject created
  And there is 1 person for that subject
  When I go to that subject persons index page
  And show me the page
  Then I should see "Back to Subjects list"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing that, which I am not proud of I ended up doing the following:

Application controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:login]

# This action is supposed to only be accessed in the test environment.
# This is for being able of running the cucumber tests.
def login
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  sign_in(@user)
  current_user = @user
  render :text => "user logged in"
end
```

Routes

```
# This is for being able of testing the application with cucumber. Since we are not using devise defaults login
match 'login/:id' => 'application#login', :as => 'login', :via => [:get] if Rails.env.test?
```

User Steps

```
Given /^I am a logged in (student|employee)+ user$/ do |role|
  @user = @that = Factory(:user, :role => role, :name => "#{role} User Name")
  Given("that user is logged in")
end

Given /^that user is logged in$/ do
  Given("I go to that users login page")
end
```

Path

```
when /that users login page/
  login_path(@that || @user)
```

This Way in my scenarios I only have to type:

```
Given I am a logged in student user
```

And the rest is just normal cucumber...

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this is some nasty monkey patch I came up with.

Added this to my application_controller.

```
if Rails.env.test?
  prepend_before_filter :stub_current_user
  # UGLY MONKEY PATCH. we need a current user here.
  def stub_current_user
    unless user_signed_in?
      @user = Factory(:user)
      sign_in(@user)
      current_user = @user
    end
  end
end
```

Remember I do not have sign_in form in my application, and I am using devise. I will, maybe later, try to look for a better approach, but for now, this let me have things done.